# determine how long a message has been queued

Tags: wcf

im using throttling on one of my services. Its hosted in a windows service and its configured with ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple and InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single. In my app.config i set maxConcurrentCalls="10". So in case my service is working on 10 calls and another one comes in it is being queued by wcf until my service finished working on at least one call. Right? Since my service's client send a timeout interval with each request (once this interval expires the service is supposed to quit processing and return a notification to the client) i need to know how long the request message has been sitting in the queue when my service starts processing it. How can i determine this?

Thanks,
J.

Comment: You can get this information using svclogs but not advised in production.